# Navigation Architecture Component - Login screen

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I am planning to implement navigation like this:
[image]
The problem I face is when user is in `LoginFragmennt` and presses back button it again loads up `LognFragment` ie. stuck in loop.

I navigate to `LoginnFragment` using conditional navigation as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493988/how-to-implement-conditional-navigation-in-navigation-architecture-components/50512729#50512729) answer.

How to properly implement this?

Comment: You stuck in loop because on pressing back you returning to previous fragment, but because the same condition is still occur(user not logged for example) you navigating to LoginFragment. What is your scenario? where you want to be navigated on pressing back?

Comment: I want to close app when user presses back button

Comment: Like in other apps at first time when you encounter login screen and press back button the app closes

Comment: Try this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51589910/1268507

Comment: Official documentation has a post about this problem https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an official solution suggested by Ian Lake in [Navigating navigation video](https://youtu.be/09qjn706ITA?t=284) at Jul 23, 2020 on [Android Developers](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVHFbqXqoYvEWM1Ddxl0QDg) YouTube channel. The solution is based on navigation [2.3 release](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#version_230_3) which introduced an [ability to return a result](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result) to the previous destination.

In our case the login fragment returns `LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL` state to the previous destination, it might be the profile fragment or any other fragment which requires login.

```kotlin
class LoginFragment : Fragment(R.layout.login) {
    ...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val navController = findNavController()
        val savedStateHandle = navController.previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle
            ?: throw IllegalStateException("the login fragment must not be a start destination")
            
        savedStateHandle.set(LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL, false)
        // Hook up your UI, ask for login
        
        userRepository.addLoginSuccessListener {
            savedStateHandle.set(LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL, true)
            navController.popBackStack()
        } 
    }
}
```

The profile fragment subscribes to the `LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL` state and processes it. Note that the observer lambda won't be called until the login fragment put a result in and return back to the profile fragment.

```kotlin
class ProfileFragment : Fragment(R.layout.profile) {
    ...
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val navController = findNavController()
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            userRepository.userFlow.collect { user -> 
                if (user == null) {
                    navController.navigate(R.id.login)
                }
            }
        }
        
        val savedStateHandle = navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle
            ?: throw IllegalStateException()
        
        savedStateHandle.getLiveData<Boolean>(LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL)
            .observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { success -> 
                if (!success) {
                    // do whathever we want, just for an example go to
                    // the start destination which doesn't require login
                    val startDestination = navController.graph.startDestination
                    navController.navigate(startDestination, navOptions {
                        popUpTo(startDestination {
                            inclusive = true
                        })
                    })
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

IMHO how I do it in my app is a little cleaner. Just add these settings in the nav graph:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/profile_dest"
    android:name="com.example.ProfileFragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_profile_dest_to_login_dest"
        app:destination="@id/login_dest"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/profile_dest"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />       
</fragment>
```

and then navigate to login via

`findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_profile_dest_to_login_dest)`.

popUpTo and popUpToInclusive close `ProfileFragment` when we navigate to `LoginFragment` so if the user navigates back, it exits the app.

Comment: On successful login then how do we get back to the ProfileFragment? Should login_dest also have an action to navigate to profile_dest and we call navigate?

Comment: Yes exactly. Like it is shown in the diagram in the question. This action should also close (remove from backstack) the login screen.

Comment: So I implemented my navigation this way and it appeared to work, however now when I go to the conditional screen (in my case login) and upon successful login navigate back (lets say to ProfileFragment as in the original post) and rotate the screen my app crashes with the error: `IllegalStateException("unknown destination during restore: id/profile_dest`. Not sure why this would happen.

Comment: What code did you use to navigate back? You should follow the same process with `popUpTo="@+id/login_dest"` and `popUpToInclusive="true"`. Don't use `popBackStack()`

Comment: You probably already did that. FWIW I haven't seen this issue. Make sure you're on the latest nav version, post another questions with your code so we can have a look, and add an issue to Googles issuetracker if you think it's a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your help and yes I'm using navigate and not popBackStack() to navigate back. I've posted a separate question about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496008/android-navigation-component-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unknown-destinati

Comment: This issue is [fixed](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#1.0.0-beta01) in 1.0.0-beta01 apparently

Answer (score 6):

One of the solutions that i can propose is to override inside your activity onBackPressed method, and finish the activity if your current destination(before on back pressed handled) is login fragment.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val currentDestination=NavHostFragment.findNavController(nav_host_fragment).currentDestination
    when(currentDestination.id) {
        R.id.loginFragment -> {
            finish()
        }
    }
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

Comment: This solution works. Now I have a doubt. For closing a activity I would use `exit(0)`. What is the difference between `exit(0)` and `finish()`?

Comment: exit(0) will kill your application, finish() finishing your activity. Don't use exit(0).