# Android Navigation Component: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unknown destination during restore

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using Android's AAC Navigation Component and have implemented conditional navigation for my login flow as described in this post: [Navigation Architecture Component - Login screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51582674/7648952)

Now everything appears to be working, however after being navigated to the login screen and successfully logging in then navigating back to the main screen, on rotation the app crashes with the following error:

```
--------- beginning of crash
2019-02-02 13:08:28.423 6030-6030/uk.co.victoriajanedavis.chatapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: uk.co.victoriajanedavis.chatapp, PID: 6030
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uk.co.victoriajanedavis.chatapp/uk.co.victoriajanedavis.chatapp.presentation.ui.main.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4699)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1595)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unknown destination during restore: uk.co.victoriajanedavis.chatapp:id/friendsFragment
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:483)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:459)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:424)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:406)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:226)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2414)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:844)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1129)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3132)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:133)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:345)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:324)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:141)
        at uk.co.victoriajanedavis.chatapp.presentation.ui.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4699)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1595)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-02-02 13:08:28.423 6030-6030/uk.co.victoriajanedavis.chatapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Here is my nav_graph.xml (the id's responsible for the login flow are @+id/action_friendsFragment_to_loginFlowGraph, @+id/action_loginFragment_to_chatFlowGraph, @+id/action_signupFragment_to_chatFlowGraph):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/chatFlowGraph">

    <!-- Chat Flow (nested graph) -->
    <navigation android:id="@+id/chatFlowGraph"
        app:startDestination="@id/friendsFragment">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/friendsFragment"
            android:name="uk.co.victoriajanedavis.chatapp.presentation.ui.friends.FriendRequestsToolbarFragment"
            android:label="fragment_friends"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_friend_requests_toolbar">

            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_friendsFragment_to_loginFlowGraph"
                app:destination="@id/loginFlowGraph"
                app:popUpTo="@id/chatFlowGraph"
                app:popUpToInclusive="true"
                app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_bottom"
                app:exitAnim="@anim/fade_out"
                app:popEnterAnim="@anim/fade_in"
                app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_bottom"/>

            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_friendsFragment_to_chatFragment"
                app:destination="@id/chatFragment"/>

            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_friendsFragment_to_friendRequestsFragment"
                app:destination="@id/friendRequestsFragment"
                app:enterAnim="@anim/grow_in_top_right"
                app:exitAnim="@anim/fade_out"
                app:popEnterAnim="@anim/fade_in"
                app:popExitAnim="@anim/grow_out_top_right"/>
        </fragment>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/chatFragment"
            android:name="uk.co.victoriajanedavis.chatapp.presentation.ui.chat.ChatFragment"
            android:label="fragment_chat"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_chat" />
    </navigation>

    <!-- Login/Register Flow (nested graph) -->
    <navigation android:id="@+id/loginFlowGraph"
        app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
            android:name="uk.co.victoriajanedavis.chatapp.presentation.ui.login.LoginFragment"
            android:label="fragment_login"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">

            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_chatFlowGraph"
                app:destination="@id/chatFlowGraph"
                app:popUpTo="@id/loginFlowGraph"
                app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>

            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_signupFragment"
                app:destination="@id/signupFragment"
                app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
                app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
                app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
                app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>

        </fragment>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/signupFragment"
            android:name="uk.co.victoriajanedavis.chatapp.presentation.ui.signup.SignupFragment"
            android:label="fragment_signup"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_signup">

            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_signupFragment_to_chatFlowGraph"
                app:destination="@id/chatFlowGraph"
                app:popUpTo="@id/loginFlowGraph"
                app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>

        </fragment>

    </navigation>

    <!-- FriendRequestsFragment -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/friendRequestsFragment"
        android:name="uk.co.victoriajanedavis.chatapp.presentation.ui.friendrequests.FriendRequestsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_friend_requests"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_friend_requests">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_friendRequestsFragment_to_sendFriendRequestFragment"
            app:destination="@id/sendFriendRequestFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_bottom"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/fade_out"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/fade_in"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_bottom"/>
    </fragment>

    <!-- SendFriendRequestFragment -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/sendFriendRequestFragment"
        android:name="uk.co.victoriajanedavis.chatapp.presentation.ui.friendrequests.sent.send.SendFriendRequestFragment"
        android:label="fragment_send_friend_request"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_send_friend_request" />

</navigation>
```

EDIT: using the latest navigation component version 1.0.0-alpha11

Comment: What version of Navigation are you using?

Comment: the latest - 1.0.0-alpha11

Comment: After doing some quick testing it appears this issue started happening in version alpha08. Not getting the crash and error in version alpha07. Maybe related to the bug fix [b/116831650](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116831650), so I'm not sure if my implementation is clearing the backstack properly using alpha07

Comment: Sounds like you should [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409828&template=1093757) with a sample project that reproduces your issue

Comment: The only difference I see between your implementation and mine is I don't use nested graphs. It could be a workaround for now. Maybe try `popUpTo` a specific fragment rather than the nested graph?

Comment: Can confirm I removed the nested graphs and now `popUpTo` the specific fragments and the crash no longer happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was fixed in version 1.0.0-beta01 of the navigation component.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this bug still existed even after 1.0.0-beta01

From the changelog, we can see it solved in [2.1.0-alpha04](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.1.0-alpha04)