# NavDeepLinkBuilder: deeplink to startDestination

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-deep-link

What we try to achieve is when a user taps a notification, he/she should be redirected to a certain fragment. That destination fragment is marked as `startDestination` in the graph (it has its own `.xml` file).

To create the `PendinIntent` for this, we use the [`NavDeepLinkBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavDeepLinkBuilder) like this:

```
// `this` represents the notification service.
NavDeepLinkBuilder(this)
    .setGraph(R.navigation.destination_graph)
    .setDestination(R.id.start_destination)
    .createPendingIntent()
```

where `R.id.start_destination` is the id of the fragment specified in `app:startDestination` attribute of the root `navigation` tag in the `R.navigation.destination_graph` a.k.a. the start destination of that graph.

If we try to use this, we get the following [error](https://pastebin.com/33AvGzwf). If we use any other fragment other than the one marked as `startDestination`, it works seamlessly.

Our graph is [this](https://pastebin.com/ZEp331yX).

What could be the actual case and what's a workaround?

EDIT: If the graph is just like the above one, but it's missing its `android:id` attribute and it's not included in the `BottomNavigationView`, the error changes to `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unknown destination during deep link: 0` (line 3)

EDIT2: The above scenario, but the graph has an ID this time and is not used in any BottomNavigationView. The error becomes `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unknown destination during deep link: test.ourapp.app:id/messages`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Navigation Component: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unknown destination during restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496008/android-navigation-component-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unknown-destinati) which version are you using ?

Comment: No, my usecase is different

Comment: I just noticed that your destination `start_destination` has an `action`, in the code of your post there is no `setArgument`. Also, you could try to use `NavController.createDeepLink()` to create a `deepLink` then create your `pendingIntent`.