# Navigation graph with multiple top level destinations in Java

Tags: navigation, uinavigationcontroller, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, appbar

I was following the implementation of Navigation graph with multiple top level destinations in the question that was asked in the following link in stack overflow: [Navigation graph with multiple top level destinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372539/navigation-graph-with-multiple-top-level-destinations/53390772#53390772)

According to the second answer, a set of top level destinations were created at first

```
val topLevelDestinations = setOf(R.id.garden_fragment,
        R.id.plant_list_fragment)
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(topLevelDestinations)
        .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
        .build()
```

The problem am having is that the code is in Kotlin, i understand how to implement the following part of the code in java

```
appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(topLevelDestinations)
        .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
        .build()
```

The problem is that I don't know how to implement the first part of the code in java, this one

```
val topLevelDestinations = setOf(R.id.garden_fragment,
        R.id.plant_list_fragment)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple Set<> with your top level destinations

```
navController = Navigation
            .findNavController(binding.navHostFragment);
    Set<Integer> topLevelDestinations = new HashSet<>();
    topLevelDestinations.add(R.id.garden_fragment);
    topLevelDestinations.add(R.id.plant_fragment);
    topLevelDestinations.add(R.id.settingsFragment);
    appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(topLevelDestinations).build();
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
```